# How to find the most commonly repeated set of double's in a text file? -Java

Tags: java

I have a text file with several hundred doubles separated by line breaks:

Ex:

```
-0.020000000000010232
0.09500000000001307
-0.05500000000000682
0.1599999999999966
0.07000000000000739
-0.0799999999999983
-0.07000000000000739
0.060000000000002274
0.04000000000000625
0.04999999999999716
-0.10000000000000853 ...
```

For further context, I'm trying a super simple version of the application of machine learning to stocks, where derivative series of differences in price are dumped in a text file. The program, whilst constantly updating the "top three" patterns, will attempt to reference a pattern whenever it sees similar derivative values to predict future changes. Less relevantly, several other heuristics considering both volatility and volumes are also included in the refinement of these patterns.

The first part of this is finding/guessing basic patterns from the text file. I have two questions here:

1. How do I round off these values to the fourth decimal point?
   (0.0001)
2. How do I find the three most commonly repeated sets of rounded
   doubles and write them to a separate text file?

Comment: 1. Do you mean repeated most often, longest repeating group, or most frequent?

Comment: Repeated most often, longest repeating group.

Comment: I meant repeated most often (e.g. repeated in 5 places) OR longest repeating group (the longest sequence of repeats was 5)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think OP means repeated most often

Comment: @DebosmitRay I think the OP wants a frequency count, only because that is usually what people ask for.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes yes. I had not noticed the point about 'frequency of a set'. So, my answer just created a frequency table of each double value. If OP does want something along the lines of a pattern freq, can you think of something better than an o(n^3) (might be wrong with the order) ?

Comment: @DebosmitRay you can do O(n) in each case, a full sort would be O(m log m) but if you only need top 3 you can simplify this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ah! Yes. I see what you are referring to. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a frequency count in O(n) like this.

```
Map<Double, Long> freqMap = DoubleStream.of(doubles).boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> round4(d), Collectors.counting());
// you can sort by the count getting just the top 3.
```

While DecimalFormat will do the job, it is really slow.  You can just use some [Maths](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Core/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/core/Maths.java).

```
private static final double WHOLE_NUMBER = 1L << 53;
/**
 * Performs a round which is accurate to within 1 ulp. i.e. for values very close to 0.5 it
 * might be rounded up or down. This is a pragmatic choice for performance reasons as it is
 * assumed you are not working on the edge of the precision of double.
 *
 * @param d value to round
 * @return rounded value
 */
public static double round4(double d) {
    final double factor = 1e4;
    return d > WHOLE_NUMBER / factor || d < -WHOLE_NUMBER / factor ? d :
            (long) (d < 0 ? d * factor - 0.5 : d * factor + 0.5) / factor;
}
```

For example,

```
double[] doubles = { 0.123400000000000, 0.123399999999997};
for (double d : doubles) {
    System.out.println(round4(d));
}
```

prints

```
0.1234
0.1234
```

---

As an exercise I though I would test this brute force for every possible values between 0.0001 and 9.99995 using multiple threads.

```
double[] ds = new double[17];
ds[0] = 1e-4;
for (int i = 1; i < ds.length; i++)
    ds[i] = 2 * ds[i - 1];

DoubleStream.of(ds).parallel()
        .forEach(x -> {
            int counter = 0;
            for (double d = x; d <= 2 * x && d < 9.99995; d += Math.ulp(d)) {
                if (Double.toString(Maths.round4(d)).length() > 6)
                    fail("d: " + d);
                if ((counter & 127) == 0 && counter % 10_000_000 == 0)
                    System.out.println(d);
                counter++;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Depending what OP is trying to do with the rounded number, this solution may not be correct.  It works for things like "comparing 2 numbers, based on their value rounded to 4 decimal point", but not for "writing number in another text file, rounded to 4 decimal point"

Comment: @AdrianShum can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: What I mean is, in order to output a "rounded-to-4-decimal-place" number to a text file, he still need to perform formatting (by using `DecimalFormat` or by other way), else he will still see '0.123400000000000' or even things like '0.123399999999997' if he write the returned double value directly to file.

Comment: @AdrianShum Instead of saying, like X but not actually X. Can you give a specific example where if he rounds the result, he will see a problem?

Comment: @AdrianShum I have added your examples to my answer, happy to add more, because I am not clear on what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, the examples helped me understand the scope of the frequency count you were referring to earlier.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you can take a look at the [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class. It should allow you to format numbers accordingly.

Secondly, you could use a `Map` to store the (rounded) number and its occurrence in the file.

Once finished, you would go through the map and see which 3 numbers have the highest occurrence (value for a given key).

Comment: How would I implement the Map such that it would find repeated sets of occurrences rather than repeated occurrences of a single double? Example: if 0.345 is repeated 8 times and 0.233 is repeated 7 times, they are not guaranteed to be adjacent to each other on the list.

Comment: @user3532216 so you want a frequency count, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. For the fourth decimal point part.

You can use `Decimal Format` [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

```
DecimalFormatt df = new DecimalFormat( "#.0000" );
df.format(num); // 4 places of decimals
```

2a. Find the three most commonly repeated sets of rounded doubles.

Use a map data structure to map rounded decimal values to their frequencies. A `HashMap`[API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) would be great.

2b. Parse HashMap to get the most frequent decimal values and write them to a file using `PrintWriter` [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java)

Let me know if something is not clear and I will try to help you out

Comment: How does this retrieve frequencies of sets of double numbers? It appears that HashMap would order them and find their independent frequencies. Example: (0.566 appeared 9 times) vs (0.342, 0.222, 0.455, 0.333 appeared 5 times)

Comment: That part wasn't very clear from your clear. You can do some sort of an o(n^2) algorithm to see if doubles at index `i`, `i+1`,.. appear somewhere else in the string. You would use a Hashmap to store this data. Run-time wise, I can't think of anything better than o(n^2) right now.